# When submitting a form is there a way to not only send the inputs but also all the froms content?

Tags: php, html, forms, post

when submitting the form and I look in the $_POST variable, then I only find the values of the form inputs. But I want to access also all the other variables. Is there a way to send them also? e.g. how could I send also the content of multiplicator1 in the variable?

```
<form>
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td><input class="inputGewicht" name="inputFieldsInput1" value="0" /></td>
   <td class="multiplicator" id="multiplicator1">5</td>
   <td class="uniqueProduct" id="uniqueProduct1">0.00</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
<form>
```

Comment: You could put the 5 in an [hidden form input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/hidden).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use input [type="hidden"](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/html-input-typehidden/) like in following code:

```
<form>
     <table>
      <tr>
       <td><input class="inputGewicht" name="inputFieldsInput1" value="0" /></td>
       <td class="multiplicator" id="multiplicator1">5</td>
       <td class="uniqueProduct" id="uniqueProduct1">0.00</td>
      </tr>
     </table>

     <!-- Enter multiplicator1 and uniqueProduct1 values into input type hidden -->
     <input type="hidden" name="multiplicator1" value="5">
     <input type="hidden" name="uniqueProduct1" value="0.00">
 <form>
```